# Adding service reference web forms for desktop app

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, web-reference

I have two different project in same server. Lets say project A is asp.net 4.5 web forms, and project B is windows form application.(I can't merge them for some reason please dont suggest that.) I need add reference to project A to use specific function in project B and return result data project A again. But tricky part is; project B should run only once (I will enter login credentials, and enter sms confirmation code.) then while this desktop app running, I need to pass values between projects. Which way should I follow ?

Comment: Does the ASP.NET application have a web API that you can use? ASP applications don't really do anything unless they are running on a web server, so just referencing it will probably not let you do what you are asking.

Comment: @RonBeyer I am afraid I dont have web api, thats why I need to connect these projects.

Comment: WCF is great for interprocess communication. You could host an endpoint in project A. Project B would be the client and make client calls. You can host WCF within the project without having to setup anything in IIS.

Comment: Thank you @sean, but I am pretty zero about WCF, can you guide me for my scenario ?

Comment: There are many tutorials/examples like http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/531332/Implementing-a-Basic-Hello-World-WCF-Service-v

Comment: Or https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766(v=vs.110).aspx